# Design Advice using Master Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

Master Page

```
  <div id="header" style="height: 150px; width: 750px;">
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="LoggedInUser:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblLoggedInUser" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div id="leftMenu" class="leftmenu">
          <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFamilyMembers" runat="server" 
              style="height: 25px; width: 125px" DataTextField="FullName" 
              DataValueField="MembershipGen" 
              onselectedindexchanged="ddlFamilyMembers_SelectedIndexChanged" 
              AutoPostBack="True" >
        </asp:DropDownList>
          <br /><br />
          <asp:Image ID="imageMember" class="space" runat="server" Height="150px" Width="125px" />
          <br /><br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" class="space" Text="MembershipID:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMembershipID" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" class="space"  Text="Name:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMemberName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

        <br /><br /><br />
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lbInformation" class="space" runat="server" onclick="lbInformation_Click">Member Information</asp:LinkButton><br />
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lbAddress" class="space" runat="server" 
              onclick="lbAddress_Click">Member Address</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>

<div id="divRight" class="divright">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPHMain" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
```

I posted my masterpage code so you can better understand my issue. Since these controls are in my master page I needed to create public properties for all the controls in my masterpage to databind my content pages. Maybe I am approaching this wrong but this is how I was planning on achieving this.

ContentPage
Default.aspx `page_load` event would call my method to retrieve the data and set the dropdownlist, image, 2 label fields. On selected index change of dropdownlist it would grab the new values from another method and populate those controls accordingly.

To access these controls in my master page i read you can do it a couple of different ways one is to `<%@MasterType VirtualPath="~/Member.Master" %>` and then create a strongly typed connection. Or you could create a loosely type connection.

My problem with these ways as I am going to have over 15 content pages and I would hate to have to rebind the DropDownList every time one of the content pages is called. Also I would have to reinstantiate the controls in every method of my content pages which I assume I am doing this wrong.

Can someone give me some advice on what is the proper way to achieve this without  so much repetitive code?

Comment: The question is not clear to me. So on changing the dropdown on masterpage, the contentpage changes? or different contentpage need to have different options in the dropdown list so you need to pass those data to the function in the masterpage and you are using a public function in master page for that?

Comment: I am confused what does the drop down list in the master page have to do with loading things in the content pages? Or are you saying that the loading of the content page causes a change in the master page (specifically the drop down list)?

Comment: Sorry I tried to explain it as best as possible. If the dropdownlist which holds different members is changed the form will update with that members information.

Comment: So basically you want to pass data from masterpage to content page, am i correct? based on the value of dropdown

Comment: yes but without using repetitive code

Comment: So yea on `selectedindexchanged` of the dropdown call a function as suggested by @garrison nelly. That should do it. Or on selected index you could redirect the page with the selected value in the querystring and grab that value in content page and load the form based on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea, trying to decouple the parent from the child, but I think the way you want to do it may be clunky.

Assuming you can do this, what I'd do is as follows:

- Make a public method `BindFamilyMembers(string parameter)` on the Master page's code-behind.
- From the child page, pass necessary unique parameters to this `BindFamilyMembers` Master method.

This way you don't need to expose the controls themselves, you expose a method that modifies those controls based on parameters.

**edit**

You want to notify the child page that the DDL SelectedIndex has changed.  This is a great case for custom events.

You can configure an event on the Master page that the child page listens for.  When DDL.SelectedIndex changes, you can fire the custom event (and pass the selected information) via the custom event, and any child page that is listening can handle that event.

There are a lot of examples of custom events online.  Here's one you can start with: http://www.marten-online.com/csharp/simple-custom-event-handling.html

Comment: Also this must be done before the page_load of the content page as the page_load of master page executes before the page_load of content page

Comment: You don't have to do it that way, but that is an option.

Comment: the dropdownlist will hold a list of members when the user changes the member my plan is to update the form based on the dropdownlist value how will this effect me

Comment: So each of the child pages represents one of the members?  If so, this would still work.

Comment: each of the child pages represent profile information for the member such as first child page would be member information... second child page would be member address third would be member school info... and when you are on that child page if the user decides to switch the member in the dropdownlist i wanted to update the form based on the selected member in the dropdownlist

Comment: Ok, edited my answer with info about custom events.  This is the best way in my opinion.

Comment: I know I am not suppose to say thanks but this was a fast and great answer I will attempt to do this but I really appreciate your help